# iOS Facebook login dialog doesn't close for some reasons

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add Facebook login to my app through Firebase and the Facebook SDK.

I've been spending hours trying to implement it but every time I have the same issue: **The login window won't close until I click OK**, so the login fails (canceled by user).

I tried to implement it in a clean app with the same Facebook configuration (same FB app, same bundle ID) and TADAA, it works as expected.

I checked the FB configuration 10 times. I removed everything and tried again, but no luck, it's not working.

It is probably due to an external conflict within my iOS app but I have no clue about where to start digging.

I don't even know what code I could post to help you as it's pretty straightforward and the exact same code in a clean app works.

Any idea?

[image: plist]

Comment: check the info.plist?

Comment: I've added the info.plist , it's basically the same than the one in the clean app where the login works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came from the fact that Firebase swizzles AppDelegate

It worked by changing FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled